# Can't get rid of color in UITableView's tableFooterView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a standard UITableView with three sections. At the bottom of the table I'm trying to add a `tableFooterView`. It seems as though there's a standard spacing between the last row in the table and the top of the `tableFooterView`, which is fine, but my problem is that there is a different color in this spacing that I can't get rid of. I need that spacing to match the background of my `tableView`.

Here's some code:

```
self.menuTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.menuTable.backgroundView = nil;
self.menuTable.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.menuTable.delegate = self;
self.menuTable.sectionHeaderHeight = 10.0;

UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
footer.backgroundColor = self.menuTable.backgroundColor;
UILabel *footerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 205, 100)];
footerLabel.text = @"foo bar.";
footerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
footerLabel.backgroundColor = self.menuTable.backgroundColor;
footerLabel.numberOfLines = 10;
footerLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
[footerLabel sizeToFit];

[footer addSubview:footerLabel];
self.menuTable.tableFooterView = footer;
```

Here's a screenshot (sorry about the red, but it's the easiest way to see the differences in colors).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whoops. Earlier I was trying to add a sectionFooterView, and had implemented `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`, returning 20 for the last section. That's where that gap was coming from, and it had a default color of white. Since I'm now placing the text as the `tableFooterView`, I just removed that delegate callback and everything is rendering as expected.

Comment: it's my own question, so i have to wait another day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.menuTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: good idea, but unfortunately the gap is now just white. if i set both the view and tableview to red, i get the same color mix as the screenshot above.

Comment: No you need to set tableView transparent and view red color even if it's not working then do one more thing. In your app delegate make window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: even after all these if it does not work send me code if you can and I will fix it.

Comment: figured it out, see my answer below.

Comment: @djibouti33 Good buddy